# Simple OpenGL ES 2.0 app on Android displaying blank screen: why?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

So I'm following the book Open GL ES 2 for Android by Kevin Brothaler and I'm trying out the first chapter's project, which is basically coloring the screen red. I set up by Samsung Galaxy Note 3 so I can debug my app on there, and also set up an emulator that uses the host GPU for rendering. Also, I forced GPU rendering on my phone. I copied the code he had exactly into my eclipse project. Here's the code for reference:

```
package com.firstopenglproject.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
//import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstOpenGLProjectActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = FirstOpenGLProjectActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
private boolean rendererSet = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Before calling super.onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "Before creating a new GLSurfaceView");
    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "Creating activity manager");
    final ActivityManager activityManager = 
            (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating configuration info");
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo =
            activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();

    Log.d(TAG, "Getting supportsEs2 boolean");
    final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
//              || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1
//              && (Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
//              || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
//              || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
//              || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
//              || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")));
    Log.d(TAG, "supportsEs2 = " + supportsEs2);
    if (supportsEs2) {
        // Request an OpenGLES2 compatible context
        glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

        // Assign our renderer
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new FirstOpenGLProjectRenderer());
        rendererSet = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device supports OpenGL ES 2.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "rendererSet is true");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OGLES2.0 not supported");
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support OpenGL ES 2.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (rendererSet) {
        glSurfaceView.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (rendererSet) {
        glSurfaceView.onResume();
    }
}

}
```

The logging tasks were ones that I added so that I can see whether the code is executing properly, and it is: I see all these log messages in LogCat. Here's the code for the renderer:

```
package com.firstopenglproject.android;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

public class FirstOpenGLProjectRenderer implements Renderer {

private static final String TAG = FirstOpenGLProjectRenderer.class.getSimpleName();
/*
 * GLSurfaceView calls this when its time to draw a frame. We must
 * draw something, even if its only to clear the screen. The rendering buffer
 * will be swapped and displayed on the screen after this method returns, 
 * so if we don't draw anything, we'll probably get a bad flickering effect.
 * */
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
    // clear the rendering surface
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

/*
 * GLSurfaceView calls this after the surface is created and whenever the size has 
 * changed. A size change can occur when switcheing from portrait to landscape
 * and vice versa.
 */
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    // set the openGL viewport to fill the entire surface
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

/*
 * GLSurfaceView calls this when the surface is created. This happens the first
 * time our application is run, and it may also be called when the device wakes 
 * up or when the user switches back to our activity. In practice, this means that
 * this method may be called multiple times while our application is still running.
 */
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

}
```

As you can see, I only use 3 calls to static methods in the GLES20 package. When I run this app on my phone and on my emulator I get a blank screen: what is going on? I've been banging my head on the table for the last 2 hours about this, and this is as simple as it could possibly get. It's supposed to display a red screen. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @JRowan alright I'll try that when I get home, thanks.

Comment: @JRowan just tried it, it still doesn't work. I really can't figure out for the life of me why this doesn't work. God this is annoying.

Comment: in your onCreate method your not setting the view, setContentView(glSurfaceView);

Comment: sorry i didnt even look at all your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not setting the view in your OnCreate() method at the end of that method add:

```
setContentView(glSurfaceView);
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I saw it on the guys website first and tried on the emulator, still didn't work but then I tried it on my phone...finally!